# How to extract XML data using Java in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have the following XML document which I'm trying to get the inner text. I have tried numerous ways, using Xpath, DOM, SAX but no success.

This is my XML, I'm not sure if it's the XML structure which is causing a problem or my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfPurchaseEntitites xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<PurchaseEntitites>
<rInstalmentAmt>634.0</rInstalmentAmt>
<rAnnualRate>12.0</rAnnualRate>
<rInterestAmt>2670.0</rInterestAmt>
<dFirstInstalment>3/31/2016 12:00:00 AM</dFirstInstalment>
<dLastInstalment>8/31/2018 12:00:00 AM</dLastInstalment>
<rInsurancePremium>1350.0</rInsurancePremium>
<sResponseCode>00</sResponseCode>
</PurchaseEntitites>
</ArrayOfPurchaseEntitites>


 InputStream stream = connect.getInputStream();
                DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                documentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
                DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = documentBuilder.parse(stream);
                doc.normalize();

                System.out.println("===============================================================");
                String g = doc.getDocumentElement().getTextContent();
                System.out.println(g);

                NodeList rootNodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("ArrayOfPurchaseEntitites");
                Node rootnode =rootNodes.item(0);
                Element rootElement = (Element) rootnode;
                NodeList noteslist = rootElement.getElementsByTagName("PurchaseEntitites");

                for(int i = 0; i < noteslist.getLength(); i++)
                {
                    Node theNote = noteslist.item(i);
                    Element noteElement =(Element) theNote;

                    Node theExpiryDate = noteElement.getElementsByTagName("dLastInstalment").item(0);
                    Element dateElement = (Element) theExpiryDate;
                    System.out.println(dateElement.getTextContent());
                }

                stream.close();
```

Comment: write your xml parser

Comment: What do you mean by "numerous ways"? Can you be more specific and show some code?

Comment: You may have a look at this tutorial : http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=152

Comment: @QueryLars , i have included my code above

Comment: @NJNileshJ                                                                                                                                  above is my parser, please advise where am i going wrong

Comment: i have tried that tutorial, but my xml document structure is different which is why im not having any luck

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where I wanted to call `getElementsByTagName` for the first `item` in a `NodeList`. The trick - which you already utilize - is to cast the `Node` to `Element`. However, just to be sure, I suggest you add `if (rootnode instanceof Element)`.

Assuming you use packages `javax.xml.parsers` and `org.w3c.dom` (no wild guess) your code works nicely when the xml is read from a file.

So if there still a problem with the code (it's been a while since this question was asked) I suggest you update the question with more info regarding `connect.getInputStream();`.